# Delete middle-character of string array in Javascript using splice

Tags: javascript, string

I want to write a function that inserts the pipe symbol in the middle of the string if the string-length is even, otherwise delete the middle character and insert the pipe symbol. For instance:

```js
isolateIt('abcd', 'efgh'); // should return ['ab|cd', 'ef|gh']
isolateIt('abcd','abcde', 'efghe'); // should return ['ab|cd', 'ab|de', 'ef|he']
```

My try:

```js
function isolateIt(array) {
    let newarray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].length%2 !== 0) {
            newarray.push(array.splice(array[i].length % 2 + 1, 1, '|'))
        } else {
            newarray.push(array.splice(array[i].length,'|'))
        }
    }
    return newarray
}
```

When I run the function I get:

```js
isolateIt(["1234", '12345', '1234', '123456']);
/// returns [ [], [ '1234' ], [ '|' ], [] ]
```

What is the correct approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a full working example:

```js
function spliceString(str, index, count, add) {
  if (index < 0) {
    index = str.length + index;
    if (index < 0) {
      index = 0;
    }
  }

  return str.slice(0, index) + (add || "") + str.slice(index + count);
}

function isolate(string) {
  let midpoint = string.length / 2;
  if (string.length % 2 == 0) {
    string = spliceString(string, midpoint, 0, "|");
  } else {
    string = spliceString(string, midpoint, 1, "|");
  }
  return string;
}

function isolateIt(...args) {
  return args.map(isolate);
}

console.log(isolateIt('abcd', 'efgh', 'abcde', 'efghe'));
// logs ["ab|cd", "ef|gh", "ab|de", "ef|he"]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is to modify the string instead of splicing the whole array

```js
function isolateIt(array) {
  let newarray = []; 

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    const mid = Math.floor(array[i].length / 2)
    if (array[i].length % 2 !== 0) {
      newarray.push(array[i].replace(array[i][mid], "|"));
    } else {
      const newStr = array[i].slice(0, mid) + '|' + array[i].slice(mid)
      newarray.push(newStr);
    }
  }
  return newarray;
}

const newArray = isolateIt(["1234", "12345", "1234", "123456"]);
console.log(newArray)
```